# What is a Class 2 Transformer

Tags: transformer

I need to replace a damaged 120V-12V transformer that is a European sourced Comelit Model 542012/A, also marked as "Class 2 Transformer" supplying power to a halogen table lamp. My question is what is the meaning/importance of the "Class 2" designation?

Answer (score 14):

Class 2 refers to a transformer that delivers 100VA or less with a maximum output voltage of \$30\text{V}_\text{AC}\text{ }\$ or less.  Class 2 transformers are limited, either by inherent winding impedance or external fusing, to power levels considered safe enough to receive special consideration in safety requirement compliance.

They are covered by standard [UL 5085-3](http://ulstandardsinfonet.ul.com/scopes/scopes.asp?fn=5085-3.html), for which UL will be glad to take your money (link is summary only).

Answer (score 0):

Class II transformers are specifically different in the sense that it's a low energy device - its secondary windings impedance is inherently higher thus its inductive reactance limits available current to its load.

Answer (score 0):

Class 2 devices are also called "double-insulated"; it is safe to use equipment
with such transformers even if a protective ground is not also present.
So, most two-prong plug power bricks are Class 2.    This allows
a two-wire cord from the power brick to the desk lamp, and the desk
lamp need not have a ground connection either.

A Class 2 electric drill might completely lack metal enclosure parts,
and have a two-prong AC power plug, while a three-prong AC power plug
is used for a non-Class 2 drill.

Comment: "Class II" (Roman numerals) is an IEC definition and refers to isolation; "Class 2" is an NEC definition which refers to power. See: https://www.cui.com/blog/class-2-vs-class-ii-power-supplies